# Windows Dos Command File Not Found (connect:direct Process)

Tags: windows, ftp, connect-direct

I am using **Connect:Direct** process to run a DOS command to get the list of files available for collection.

If the files are available in the collection folder then the file details gets redirected to the output file `(dirfile.lst)`. Then Connect:Direct will do a collection for those files and then delete dirfile.lst.
If there are no files in the collection folder it is expected that the dirfile.lst will be empty. And Connect:Direct will collect no files and delete dirfile.lst.

The command which I am using is

```
(dir "G:\Outbound\EDI\USCOLL_FTP\*" /a-d/oN ) > "F:\Sterling\Connect Direct v4.6.00\Server\program\2172047.dirfile.lst"
```

The problem which I am facing is when the file filter is `.` or `*.*`   and if there are no files in the folder then the command throws a response "File Not Found". Connect:Direct process fails when it gets any response from the command. Interestingly I only face this issue is the file filter is *.* or *  for any other file filter I am not getting this "File Not Found" response even though there are no files in the folder.

If I use `2> Null` to fix the issue it won't display any other exceptions, hence I don't prefer to use this?

**Is there a way I can get rid of File not Found message which I get when I use * and *.* file filters?**

Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not pretty, but this should do the trick:

```
>NUL 2>NUL DIR "G:\Outbound\EDI\USCOLL_FTP\*" /a-d/oN && (DIR "G:\Outbound\EDI\USCOLL_FTP\*" /a-d/oN > "F:\Sterling\Connect Direct v4.6.00\Server\program\2172047.dirfile.lst") || ECHO. > "F:\Sterling\Connect Direct v4.6.00\Server\program\2172047.dirfile.lst"
```

I know you didn't want to use `2>Nul` but it's the best I could get. Hopefully someone will provide a better answer.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I tried the above solution but the dirfile.list is not created.

Comment: I thought that was the point? If no files are found it won't create `dirfile.list` - are you saying that you want a blank file in this case?

Comment: Sorry if I confused you. Yes if there are no files then I want an empty dirfile.list file

Comment: edited the answer - see above. Basically replace `ECHO. > NUL` with `ECHO. > ...dirfile.list`